# Does LFR loot in Mists account for a role/spec mismatch?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In Mists of Pandaria LFR, loot is won individually and rewarded according to spec.  However, what happens if I queue as a healer, and participate in the kill as DPS?

For example: I'm a druid with a Feral and Resto spec.  I queue as a healer (presumably to get a shorter queue time), but I kill the boss doing DPS in my Feral spec.  This being LFR, the other 5 healers have no issue making up for my lack of healing (provided they are not doing the same thing I am).

Assuming the relevant items on the boss loot table are leather agility wrists and a spirit ring, will I be awarded the wrists or the ring?

Comment: Do healers really get shorter queue times in LFR?

Comment: Yes, significantly so (or at least they used to).

Comment: They still do.  It'll be instant and at Madness if you queue for the 2nd half, or it'll take maybe a minute to get a fresh run if you've already killed Madness.

I suppose I was working under the assumption that something similar will happen in MoP, as the tank/healer/DPS ratios aren't changing.

Comment: ...which can be tedious because quite often you're forced to queue two separate times just to kill all 4 bosses. When queueing as heals, it seems to me that 90% of the time I get into a run already in progress. But as Nick states, heal wait times are usually little to nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

Potential loot from boss drops in LFR look only at your current spec.

[Blizz Quote:](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/4217173624#15)

> Second, the item you win will be “useful” in the sense that it’s
>   potentially usable by your current spec. This does not mean that
>   warriors will get leather because warriors can equip leather (at a
>   huge stat loss). It also does not mean that the game will always give
>   you an item you want or an upgrade for the items you have. It just
>   looks and says “You are a Holy priest, so here is a random item chosen
>   from the Holy priest-appropriate items that this boss can drop.”

The potential bonus roll follows the same rules.

Comment: I suppose we'll leave it as an experiment to see if this will be a real problem, or if the fear of wiping will cause people to perform the proper role.

Comment: Actually, players doing this don't fear the wipe (and I hope that you're not because it really is taking advantage of the system), but rather fear being booted for not doing what they queued for. People aren't stupid. They'll realize that you queued for heals because of the low wait time, but really just wanted to dps and roll on dps gear. Its easy to get away with this in cataclysm now because everyone is overgeared for LFR, but shouldn't be as easy come MoP.